Spring Data JPA OneToMany relationship
I have an Web Application where I have to develop functionality like:

I have Entities as:
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses;
}

and
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "email_addresses")
public class EmailAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

}

DTOs for both are:
public record ContactDto(
        UUID id,
        @NotBlank
        String name,
        @NotBlank
        String title,
        @NotBlank
        String phone,
        @NotBlank
        String address,
        @NotBlank
        String status,
        @NotBlank
        String imgUrl,
        List<EmailAddressDto> emailAddresses
) implements Serializable {}

and
public record EmailAddressDto(
        UUID id,
        @Email String email
) implements Serializable {}

There is ContactService where I save the contact and related Email Addresses as:
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class) // If exception occurs undo all transactions
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;
    private final EmailAddressService emailAddressService;
    private final ContactMapper contactMapper;
    private final EmailMapper emailMapper;

    
    @Override
    public ContactDto createContact(ContactDto contactDto) {
        var newSavedContact = contactRepository.save(contactMapper.asEntity(contactDto));
        var contactId = newSavedContact.getId().toString();
        contactDto.emailAddresses().forEach(
                emailAddress -> {
                    emailAddressService.createEmailByContactId(contactId, emailAddress);
                }
        );
        newSavedContact.setEmailAddresses(
                emailMapper.asEntityList(emailAddressService.getAllEmailByContactId(contactId))
        );
        return contactMapper.asDTO(contactRepository.save(newSavedContact));
    }

    
    @Override
    public int updateContact(String id, ContactDto contactDto) {
        int affected_rows = 0;
        if (getContactById(id) != null) {
            affected_rows = contactRepository.updateContactById(
                    contactDto.name(),  contactDto.title(),
                    contactDto.phone(), contactDto.address(), contactDto.status(),
                    contactDto.imgUrl(), UUID.fromString(id));
        }
        // Update Emails
        var newSavedContact = contactRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
        var contactId = newSavedContact.getId().toString();
        AtomicInteger rows_affected = new AtomicInteger();
        contactDto.emailAddresses().forEach(
                emailAddress -> {
                    rows_affected.addAndGet(emailAddressService.updateEmailById(emailAddress.id().toString(), emailAddress));
                }
        );
        newSavedContact.setEmailAddresses(
                emailMapper.asEntityList(emailAddressService.getAllEmailByContactId(contactId))
        );
        // Save updated contact
        contactRepository.save(newSavedContact);
        log.error("ROWS_AFFECTED => {}", rows_affected);
        return affected_rows;
    }

}

and EmailService class is
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class) // If exception occurs undo all transactions
public class EmailAddressServiceImpl implements EmailAddressService {

    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;
    private final EmailAddressRepository emailAddressRepository;
    private final EmailMapper emailMapper;

    @Override
    public List<EmailAddressDto> getAllEmailByContactId(String id) {
        Contact contact = contactRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
        return contact.getEmailAddresses().stream().map(emailMapper::asDTO).toList();
    }

    @Override
    public void createEmailByContactId(String id, EmailAddressDto emailAddressDto) {
        Contact contact = contactRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id))
                .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);

        var emailAddress = emailMapper.asEntity(emailAddressDto);
        emailAddress.setContact(contact);
        emailMapper.asDTO(emailAddressRepository.save(emailAddress));
    }

    @Override
    public int updateEmailById(String id, EmailAddressDto emailAddressDto) {
        int rows_affected = 0;
        if (!emailAddressRepository.existsById(UUID.fromString(id)))
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("record not found");

        rows_affected = emailAddressRepository.updateEmailById(
                emailAddressDto.email(), UUID.fromString(id)
        );
        return rows_affected;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmailById(String id) {
        emailAddressRepository.deleteById(UUID.fromString(id));
    }
}

The above code works fine, but is there any issue regarding performance, or is there any other way to optimize the code?
